# How to replace embedded Twitter Cards in AMP pages with amp-twitter?

Tags: amp-html, twitter-card

I am trying to replace embedded Tweet Cards with AMP suitable version.

Trying to replace this

`<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="eu" dir="ltr">An itibari ile <a href="tweet_url">[tweet url]</a>  <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/paratic?src=hash">#paratic</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/ParaticCom">@ParaticCom</a> <a href="https://tweet_url">pic.twitter.com/NpFDB7LTJQ</a></p>&mdash; Onur Celik (@onurcelik66) <a href="https://twitter.com/onurcelik66/status/856521132664643584">April 24, 2017</a></blockquote><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

with this

`<amp-twitter width='390' height='330' layout='responsive' data-tweetid='856521132664643584'></amp-twitter>`

I can not use JavaScript on AMP pages so I have to do it using PHP. Is there anyone here who can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lullabot/amp-library](https://github.com/Lullabot/amp-library) for this. It's a PHP library that converts HTML to AMPHTML.